# Query count between dates and status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a products table that looks like that:

```
ProductId(pKey) ProductTypeId
    1                 3
    2                 3
    3                 2
    4                 1
    5                 1
```

every time a row inserted to this table it mains that a new product was sold.

I have only 3 `ProductTypeId` that which actually represents a servers that my customer can cancel and recancel or be on hold status, and that leads us to the history of status products table that looks like that:

```
StatusId(pKey) ProductId StatusDate ProductStatus
1                 ,1      ,1-1-17       ,1
2                 ,1      ,2-12-17      ,2
3                 ,2      ,21-5-17       ,1
4                 ,3      ,11-5-18       ,1
5                 ,2      ,18-5-18       ,2
6                 ,2      ,10-8-18       ,3
```

I have only 3 types of status ("ProductStatus" column) 1,2,3.

**my goal is to count every month how many `ProducsType` were in status 1.**

the column `StatusDate` represents the date were the status changed, so the first time a customer buy the product/serves he/she will have a `ProductTypeId` (1,2 or 3) that will never change, and `ProductStatus` of 1 but can change any time in the future.

the query results should look something like that:

```
year     month      productId(1)     productId(2)     productId(3)
 2017      1              0               0                 1
 2017      2              0               0                 1(because the status not change)
 2017      3              0               0                 1
 2017      4              0               0                 1
 2017      5              0               0                 2
 2017      6              0               0                 2
```

and so on....

Comment: your table header definition looks like you want to count how many Products were in status 1 not how many ProducsType where in status 1

Comment: I think you're right, my mistake

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for rows in the columns and ProductTypeId const all the time. It will work.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        YEAR(s.StatusDate) AS 'Year',
        MONTH(s.StatusDate) AS 'MONTH',
        p.ProductTypeId
    FROM 
        Status s
        INNER JOIN Product p ON p.ProductId = s.ProductId
    WHERE
        s.ProductStatus = 1
    GROUP BY
        p.ProductTypeId,
        s.StatusDate
)p
PIVOT
(
COUNT(p.ProductTypeId)
FOR p.ProductTypeId IN([1],[2],[3])
)AS Pb
```

Comment: thank you, but I think I wasnt clear enough, every month the query should count every product that it is in status 1, so it means that even if the query counts, lets say march 2018, its also need to count the previous months with the status 1 that hasn't change.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong. You need to count January and February as well for March(let's say it is current month)

Comment: Yes, I added a query resulte above.

Comment: @Serhan . . . This counts the *changes* that occur in each month.  It does not count the accumulated number that have a particular status in the month.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the query but it should look sometime like this.

```
SELECT YEAR(h.StatusDate),MONTH(h.StatusDate),COUNT(p1.ProductId),
       COUNT(p2.ProductId),COUNT(p3.ProductId)
FROM HistoryTable h
left join products p1 on p1.ProductId = h.ProductId and p1.ProductTypeId = 1
left join products p2 on p2.ProductId = h.ProductId and p2.ProductTypeId = 2
left join products p3 on p3.ProductId = h.ProductId and p3.ProductTypeId = 3
WHERE h.ProductStatus = 1
GROUP BY YEAR(h.StatusDate),MONTH(h.StatusDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky.  I prefer to count values on a particular *date* rather than during a month.  This prevents multiple counting of a product during the month.

The following counts the statuses on the first day of each month.  It can be extended for any change during the month, but that risks multiple counting of a single product:

```
select v.dte,
       sum(case when h.status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as status_1,
       sum(case when h.status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as status_2,
       sum(case when h.status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as status_3
from (values (convert(date, '2017-01-01')),
             (convert(date, '2017-02-01')),
             (convert(date, '2017-03-01')),
             (convert(date, '2017-04-01')),
             (convert(date, '2017-05-01')),
             (convert(date, '2017-06-01'))
     ) v(dte) left join
     (select h.*,
             lead(status_date) over (partition by productid order by status_date) as end_status_date
      from history h
     ) h
     on v.dte >= h.status_date and
        (v.dte < h.end_status_date or h.end_status_date)
group by v.dte
order by v.dte;
```

Comment: thank you, I didnt try it yet and I have a question: is this query as a dynamic date range, because I see you entered in the code a specific dates, and my goal is to return every month and year that exists.

Comment: @nd0911 . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you want a different date range, edit the list, use a recursive CTE, or calendar table to generate the months that you really do want.

Comment: I dont know how to do it.